# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy == 1.9.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, quandl

Trying to install `quandl` and need `pandas`, so I tried `pip install pandas` and get:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.9.3 (from versions: 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1rc1, 1.11.1, 1.11.2rc1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0b1, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.1rc1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2)
> No matching distribution found for numpy==1.9.3.

I'm using `python 3.4`, `win32`

Comment: Actually, I think I might have read the error message backwards. IIRC, quandle changed from being capitalised. What do you get from `import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)`?

Comment: "after installing numpy 1.9.2" doesn't match with "satisfies the requirement numpy==1.9.3". And the current release from [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases) is 1.14.2 so I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: Hm, so 1.9.3 is actually a really old version of `numpy` and it doesn't seem to be available in pip anymore. Is there a reason for that specific requirement? You could search for an archive of the old version, but you might have better luck finding a newer version of `quandl` that works with current versions of `numpy`

Comment: Check your source for `quandl`.  A well written package shouldn't depend on a subversion like that.  It's ok to expect something newer than 1.9.3 but not exactly that.  That's too fragile.

Comment: @roganjosh I get 1.9.0!!! Which is really weird because when I update numpy I get "Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (1.14.2)"

Comment: @Jony a `pip`/`pip3` issue?

Comment: Ok, now I fixed the above issue and import numpy; print(numpy.__version__) returns 1.14.2

but I'm still getting the same error when I try to install pandas

Comment: @Jony and does everything else work? Spooky that I just checked back on the tab and opened the comment box to suggest uninstalling all packages when you made that message :)

Comment: @roganjosh, I have to go take a test now, will be back later. I had to uninstall numpy and upgrade it ignoring install in order for python to start using the right version. I thought for sure that would fix the issue but I'm still getting the same "Could not . . . No matching distribution found for numpy==1.9.3." error when I try to install pandas

Answer (score 6):

https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.22.1/#files

Latest `numpy` does not support `python 3.7` anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The current `quandl` is more generous in its requirements:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Quandl

Requires Distributions
pandas (>=0.14)
numpy (>=1.8)
```

It's `github` `setup` is the same: https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: I am using this source for quandl.

Comment: I wonder if it's a problem with a particular version of another package such as `pandas` (rather than `quandl` itself).

Answer (score 3):

Just use this command :

`pip install pandas==0.19.0` .

An older version which will not cry with this error !!

Answer (score 2):

Just Install Python 3.5 or higher.

Comment: Using python 3.7 this still happens

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, with installed python 3.6.9. Trying to install requirements with "pip install -r requirements.txt" gave me a similar error (can't find numpy version, in my case, it was 1.9.6). I tried`python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt` but it seems, for some reason the pip module for python3 hasn't been installed in my case. So, I installed it manually and repeated the command, and the requirements has been installed.

Manually installing pip [module](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel) for python3:

Securely Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Run `python3 get-pip.py`

Run `sudo apt install python3-testresources`

This will install or upgrade pip. Additionally, it will install setuptools and wheel if they’re not installed already.

"Warning: Be cautious if you’re using a Python install that’s managed by your operating system or another package manager. get-pip.py does not coordinate with those tools, and may leave your system in an inconsistent state. You can use python get-pip.py --prefix=/usr/local/ to install in /usr/local which is designed for locally-installed software."

And, finally, run `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I changed the **LASTEST VERSION** into  `requirements.txt` by `pandas == 0.23.1` - at that time was the **latest release of released** - You can check in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, we wanted to get pip modules installed from requirement*.txt files, which had **locked-in** module's versions defined in the file **and** fetched from an **internal Artifactory** server (**rather than** going to online i.e. *pypi.org*)

Ex: requirements.txt file(s)

```
numpy==1.16.2
pandas==1.0.3
..
...
```

To fix the issue: I had to use `NO_PROXY=<value>` available as an environment variable.

Let's say, if you artifactory server is: my-artifactory.**company.local** or my-artifactory.**company.com**, then all we need to ensure is that `NO_PROXY` variable has that hostname's "**domain**" part listed in its value.

i.e. for
my-artifactory.**company.com** or my-artifactory.**company.local**, value inside

NO_PROXY variable must have: `,.company.com,.company.local,...` in it.

**Sample** exported variable (**at command line $ prompt**):

`export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,169.254.169.254,169.254.169.123,.somecompany.com,.company.com,.company.local,pki.company.com,s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com,s3-fips-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com,rds.amazonaws.com,10.201.12.244,10.201.44.62,10.201.32.261`

====

If you are using a `Dockerfile`, then, ensure you have ARG/ENV variable are set correctly.
ARG is used during build time (can be overridden at command line using --build-arg option sent to `docker build -t tag .` where it'll search current directory for a Dockerfile and create an image. ENV is used at run time (`docker run`) and can be overridden as well.

**Sample Dockerfile** is:

```
FROM python:3.7

MAINTAINER giga.sangal@company.com

ARG PYTHONBUFFERED=0
ARG HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.ext.company.com:80
ARG HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.ext.company.com:80
ARG NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,169.254.169.254,.company.com,.company.local,pki.company.com,s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com,s3-fips-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com,rds.amazonaws.com

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=${PYTHONBUFFERED}
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=${HTTPS_PROXY}
ENV HTTP_PROXY=${HTTP_PROXY}
ENV NO_PROXY=${NO_PROXY}

# If there are 3 requirements files in source control, I'm copy all for pip install, you don't have to. Use what modules you want / file you want.    
RUN mkdir -p code
COPY requirements.txt /code
COPY requirements-test.txt /code
COPY requirements-dev.txt /code

WORKDIR /code

# You can fetch from pypi.org but in my case, this was a security issue.
# RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host my-artifactory.company.local -r requirements.txt -r requirements-test.txt -r requirements-dev.txt --index-url http://my-artifactory.company.local:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local-deps/simple --disable-pip-version-check
```

The main line, which solved the issue in my case, was using the NO_PROXY (as listed above).

Any issues related to pip module not found, or module version not found, or any SSL errors  `SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError` like errors, went away after applying the above NO_PROXY at **cmd line** or in **Dockerfile**:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/requests/
```

or

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests
```

or

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.16.2
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.16.2
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can also follow this steps here**

Select: Workloads → Desktop development with C++, then for Individual Components, select only:

- Windows 10 SDK
- C++ x64/x86 build tools

Can also achieve the same automatically using the following command:

```
vs_buildtools.exe --norestart --passive --downloadThenInstall --includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools
```

Go to the [link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) and download **vs_buildtools.exe**

I did that and it worked. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with OpenCV, upgrading the pip version solved the issue:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

After the update the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20697) and was told that **Pandas no longer supports Python 3.4** so you will need to install an older version of Pandas (and perhaps an older version of numpy) to work with Python 3.4.

Not terribly satisfying I know but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue installing pandas from source, branch `0.22.x`. I followed [these steps](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/contributing.html#contributiong-dev-python) and obtained this error:

```
$ python -m pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///Users/mmorin/Software/pandas
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.9.3 (from versions: 1.11.3, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.1rc1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3)
No matching distribution found for numpy==1.9.3
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20697) on GitHub where @djhoese suggested using version `9.0.3` of `pip` instead of version `10.0.1`. I added this line in `ci/environment-dev.yaml`:

```
 - pip==9.0.3
```

I gave the environment a new name for clarity, so the whole file is:

```
name: pandas-dev-pip9
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - Cython
  - NumPy
  - moto
  - pytest
  - python-dateutil
  - python=3
  - pytz
  - setuptools
  - sphinx
  - pip==9.0.3
```

Answer (score -1):

Numpy is notoriously difficult to install as it contains dependencies (optional or selectable) on various non-Python packages. I would suggest to use a different environment manager such as Enthought or [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/downloads) (which I would recommend).

If you want to do a quick start, use the full-blown anaconda distribution. If you need more explicit control, use miniconda.

Once you have anaconda installed, all you need to do to create a new conda environment (similar to a virtual environment, but with non-python packages included in the environment itself) is

```
conda create -n my_shining_environment quandl
```

The above will include quandl (at the time of writing v3.3.0), numpy and all other dependencies for quandl.