# install the pandas package in pycharm

Tags: python

When I try to install pandas, I get this error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.9.3 (from versions: 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1rc1, 1.11.1, 1.11.2rc1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0b1, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.1rc1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3)
>   No matching distribution found for numpy==1.9.3

I use

```
pip install pandas
```

and

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

In both cases, I get the same error.
Thanks.

Comment: What OS and architecture do you have?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You can update `pip` and try it again. The last version of `pip` is **10.0.1**.

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: you can try use `conda` instead of `pip`

Answer (score 0):

You have some sort of versionitis (versions of different software not being compatible with each other). If you are running Python <3.4, that could be the cause because Pandas no longer supports Python <3.4. [See this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805576/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-numpy-1-9-3).

I saw this issue on Mac OS running python 3.7 and pandas 0.23. I downgraded to python 3.6 and pandas 0.22, and that fixed my issue.